# How to use two IENumerable models in one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model, ienumerable

I am trying to use two models in one view, but from what I understand my program just don't see any objects within models.

Here is my code.

Models:

```
    public class Album
    {
        [Key]
        public int ThreadId { get; set; } 
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ThreadByUser { get; set; } 
        public string ThreadCreationDate { get; set; }
        public string ThreadContent { get; set; } 
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public List<Posts> Posty { get; set; }
    }
    public class Posts 
    {
        [Key]
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public int ThreadId { get; set; } 
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }
        public string PostContent { get; set; }
        public string PostDate { get; set; }
        public string PosterName { get; set; }
        public Album Album { get; set; }

    }

    public class ModelMix
    {
        public IEnumerable<Posts> PostsObject { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Album> ThreadsObject { get; set; }
    }
```

Index controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {

        ViewBag.ThreadId = id;
        var posts = db.Posts.Include(p => p.Album).ToList();
        var albums = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Genre).ToList();

        var mixmodel = new ModelMix
        {
            PostsObject = posts,
            ThreadsObject = albums
        };

        return View(mixmodel);
    }
```

View code:

```
@model MvcMusicStore.Models.ModelMix

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PostsObject.PostContent)
```

And when I try to execute my program I am getting this error:

> CS1061: The "
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 'does not contain a definition
>   of" PostContent "not found method of expanding" PostContent ", which
>   takes a first argument of type' System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>    "

How I can make it work as intended? There are a lot of questions like mine on the internet but I couldn't find any matching my case.

Comment: you need to iterate them in for\foreach

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looping over models can be a little confusing to begin with in MVC, only because the templated helpers (i.e. `Html.DisplayFor` and `Html.EditorFor`) can be provided templates which the helper will automatically invoke for every element in a collection.  That means if you're new to MVC, and you don't realise a `DisplayTemplate` or an `EditorTemplate` has not been provided for the collection already, it looks as though a simple:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomePropertyThatHoldsACollection)
```

is all you need.  So if you've seen something like that already, that might be why you made the assumption it would work.  However, let's assume for a moment that a template has not been provided.  You have two options.

Firstly, and most simply, would be to use `foreach` over the collection:

```
@foreach (var post in Model.PostsObject)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => post.PostTitle)
    // display other properties
}
```

You could also use a `for` loop, but with `IEnumerable<T>`, there is no indexer, so this won't work:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PostsObject.Count(); i++)
{
    // This generates a compile-time error because
    // the index post[i] does not exist.
    // This syntax would work for a List<T> though.
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => post[i].PostTitle)
    // display other properties
}
```

If you did want to use the `for` loop still, you can use it like so:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PostsObject.Count(); i++)
{
    // This works correctly
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => post.ElementAt(i).PostTitle)
    // display other properties
}
```

So use whichever you prefer.  However, at some point it would be a good idea to look into providing [templates for your types](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html). (Note: Although this article was written for MVC 2, the advice still applies.) They allow you to remove looping logic from your views, keeping them cleaner.  When combined with `Html.DisplayFor`, or `Html.EditorFor`, they will also generate correct element naming for model binding (which is great).  They also allow you to reuse presentation for a type.

One final comment I'd make is that the naming of your properties is a little verbose:

```
public class ModelMix
{
    public IEnumerable<Posts> PostsObject { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Album> ThreadsObject { get; set; }
}
```

We already know they're objects, so there's no need to add that on the end.  This is more readable:

```
public class ModelMix
{
    public IEnumerable<Posts> Posts { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Album> Threads { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I went with foreach loop. I had no idea that solution for my problem will be that simple!

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate them like this:

```
@model MvcMusicStore.Models.ModelMix

<h2>Index</h2>

@for(var i=0; i<model.PostsObject.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PostsObject[i].PostContent)
}
```

And also it's better to save IList instead of IEnumerable, as it will have Count property, instead of using Count() method

Comment: DisplayNameFor will only display titles and not actual data. These are usually for headers of tables.

Comment: yep, i know. but original question was about DisplayNameFor method , so made sample with it

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'll need to iterate through each item if you're passing in any type of `IEnumerable<>`. Since you built a semi-complex model, you'll want to display `foreach` item in each list. Here is an example based from the ASP.NET MVC tutorials that I think would help you a bit:

```
@model IEnumerable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Course>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Courses";
}

<h2>Courses</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CourseID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Credits)
        </th>
        <th>
            Department
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Credits)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CourseID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CourseID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CourseID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Generally most people use an `ICollection` for their lists, where an example might be in an object:

```
public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

Source:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I would recommend starting at the beginning as it'll help you understand why you need to do this:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc

Comment: This applies when I have only one model, I do know how that works already (I think), I already completed tutorial from the that site (but for mvc4 - the one where you make movies database), but they didn't included any examples of having two models in one view.

Comment: You can simply just decide which Model you want from the complex object. I.E. Model.Object1.Whatever / Model.Object2.Whatever